# R shiny: checkboxGroupInput Insert a placemark between checkboxes

Tags: javascript, css, r, checkbox, shiny

I need to insert text or a label between the checkboxes. How can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `checkboxGroupInput`, you can render additional HTML elements using the `choiceName` argument. In the example below, I've defined the markup using Shiny `tags` and passed values as a list

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- tagList(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
          ".label {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 6px 0;
          }",
          ".label span {
            padding: 3px;
            color: #ffffff;
          }",
          ".label .fruit {
            background: green;
          }",
          ".label .veggies {
            background: #2d7ddd;
          }",
          ".label .meat {
            background: red;
          }"
      )   
    ),
  tags$main(
    tags$h2("Custom Checkbox"),
    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = "food",
      label = NULL,
      choiceNames = list(
          tags$p(class="label", tags$span(class = "fruit", "fruit"), "Grapes"),
          tags$p(class="label", tags$span(class = "fruit", "fruit"), "Apples"),
          tags$p(class="label", tags$span(class = "veggies", "veggies"), "Carrots"),
          tags$p(class="label", tags$span(class = "veggies", "veggies"), "Celery"),
          tags$p(class="label", tags$span(class = "meat", "meat"), "Beef"),
          tags$p(class="label", tags$span(class = "meat", "meat"), "Chicken")
      ),
      choiceValues = list(
          "apples",
          "grapes",
          "carrots",
          "celery",
          "beef",
          "chicken"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe(print(input$food))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```